# Accessing django site in subfolder of multisite nginx server (default homepage works, not admin)

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to create a django site on my nginx server. I already have other site in other sub-folders. I use gunicorn service to redirect from nginx to django.

I'm able to access the default django welcome page (https://example.com/django/) but I can't go to the admin page of my django site (if I enter https://example.com/django/admin, it redirect me to https://example.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/ and I get a nginx 404). Renaming the redirection to https://example.com/django/admin/login/?next=/admin/ shows a plain html login page (like if the static content was not loaded).

I'm only starting webdev so I might be wrong, but is seems the error is in my nginx config.

Here is my nginx configuration file:

````
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    # listen 80;

    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # drop SSLv3 (POODLE vulnerability)
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location /biketrack {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    # Django configuration
    location /django/static/ {
        alias /home/pi/elops-tracker-project/static;
    }
    location /django {
        include proxy_params;
        rewrite ^/django/(.*) /$1  break;

        # alias /home/pi/elops-tracker-project
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        # proxy_redirect off;
        # proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /django
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/pi/elops-tracker-project/elops_tracker.sock;
    }
}```
````